# Can anyone explain how to zoom in/out around a clicked point(in my case double click) in flutter? Iam using the code below

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

Can anyone explain how to zoom in/out around a clicked point?In the code below it is zooming in/out at a point which I have given as alignment value in transform widget(here FractionalOffset.topRight), pich to zoom is also working fine. Is there any solution to do this? This is the code that I have.

```
class ImageZoom extends StatefulWidget {
  static String routeName = "/image_zoom";
  @override
  _ImageZoomState createState() => _ImageZoomState();
}

class _ImageZoomState extends State<ImageZoom> {
  var images = [
    "https://images.pexels.com/photos/7291782/pexels-photo-7291782.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500",
    "https://images.pexels.com/photos/4041366/pexels-photo-4041366.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500",
    "https://images.pexels.com/photos/6455888/pexels-photo-6455888.png?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500",
    "https://images.pexels.com/photos/2543240/pexels-photo-2543240.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500",
  ];
  //pageview
  int currentIndex = 0;
  PageController _controller = PageController();

  double _scale = 1.0;
  double _previousScale = 1.0;

  void moveToPage(int index) {
    if (_controller.hasClients) {
      _controller.animateToPage(
        0,
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 400),
        curve: Curves.easeInOut,
      );
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _controller.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        body: SizedBox(
          height: double.infinity,
          width: double.infinity,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Flexible(
                flex: 1,
                child: Container(
                  child: PageView.builder(
                      pageSnapping: true,
                      reverse: false,
                      controller: _controller,
                      onPageChanged: (int page) {
                        setState(() {
                          currentIndex = page % images.length;
                          _scale = 1.0;
                        });
                      },
                      itemBuilder: (_, index) {
                        return GestureDetector(
                          onDoubleTap: () {
                            setState(() {
                              _scale = 3.0;
                            });
                          },
                          onTap: () {
                            setState(() {
                              _scale = 1.0;
                            });
                          },
                          onScaleStart: (scaleDetails) {
                            _previousScale = _scale;
                            setState(() {});
                          },
                          onScaleUpdate: (scaleDetails) {
                            _scale = _previousScale * scaleDetails.scale;
                            setState(() {});
                          },
                          onScaleEnd: (scaleDetails) {
                            _previousScale = 1.0;
                            setState(() {});
                          },
                          child: Transform(
                            alignment: FractionalOffset.topRight,
                            transform: Matrix4.diagonal3(
                                Vector3(_scale, _scale, _scale)),
                            child: Image.network(
                              images[index % images.length],
                              fit: BoxFit.contain,
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                      }),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                height: 80,
                color: Colors.white,
                child: ListView.separated(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 10),
                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                  itemBuilder: (_, index) {
                    return GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        moveToPage(index);
                      },
                      child: Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            border: Border(
                              bottom: BorderSide(
                                  width: 5.0,
                                  color: currentIndex == index
                                      ? Colors.green
                                      : Colors.transparent),
                            )),
                        width: 50,
                        child: ExtendedImage.network(
                          images[index],
                          fit: BoxFit.fill,
                          cache: true,
                          clearMemoryCacheWhenDispose: true,
                          clearMemoryCacheIfFailed: true,
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                  separatorBuilder: (_, index) {
                    return SizedBox(
                      width: 5,
                    );
                  },
                  itemCount: images.length,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the user to Zoom in and out using two fingers, put your image in an **InteractiveViewer** widget.

```
Container(
      height: 4000,
      child: InteractiveViewer(
        maxScale: 25,
        child: Image.network(widget.image),
      ),
```

If you want the user to change the image size when double tapping, put your image in an inkwell and change the height and width on double tap

```
InkWell(
    onDoubleTap: () {
     setState(() {
       zoom = !zoom
     });
        Container(
          height: zoom ? 200 : 100,
          width: zoom ? 200 : 100,
          child: Image.asset(image))
      }
```

make sure to have an initial value for zoom (or whatever you want to call it in your code)

Comment: thnks@Moh'd K. Albattikhi